# Possible to detect page visits

Tags: android

Is it possible to somehow detect when a user goes to a page from within an service (or broadcast receiver) ? I would like to add a feature on my app which detects whenever the user goes to mysite.com, and show an alertdialog asking if the user wants to launch the app for a more convenient experience.

add: i should add that my app is used to browse data from mysite.com much easier.

Comment: use intent filter in your application  as specified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: thats what i needed, mind copy pasting that in a answer so i can select it as the right one?